# I had a hard time vs I had hard times

Tags: phrase-request, uncountable-nouns

I always don't understand how I can count time.

In what situation can I use "a hard/good time" or "hard/good times"?

Could you please show me examples of sentences, or explanations about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **a hard time** and **a good time** to describe specific events.

> How was the party?
> I had a good time.
>
> How was the war?
> I had a hard time getting used to the cries of wounded children.

Use **hard times** and **good times** to describe periods of extended duration. I can't provide an exact minimum, but it is likely to be a year or so. There is no real maximum. The reign of an entire family of monarchs could be described as **hard times**.

> The Great Depression lasted from the 20s through World War 2. Those were hard times for everyone.

There is a special ironic use of **good times**, at least in American usage.

> What was it like growing up with an alcoholic parent?
> Good times!

Comment: I don't think I would ever say _I had hard times_, though I would say _They were hard times_.

Answer (score 1):

Auxiliary ***to have*** coupled with singular *a **hard time*** is [by far the most common usage](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=had%20a%20hard%20time%2Chad%20hard%20times%2Cwent%20through%20hard%20times&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chad%20a%20hard%20time%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chad%20hard%20times%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwent%20through%20hard%20times%3B%2Cc0) in this area...

[image]

As you can see, comparatively speaking, plural ***had hard times*** effectively "flatlines" along with ***went through hard times*** at the bottom of that chart. But if we [remove the most common version,](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=went%20through%20a%20hard%20time%2Cwent%20through%20hard%20times&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwent%20through%20a%20hard%20time%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwent%20through%20hard%20times%3B%2Cc0) we see a different story with ***to go through*** - where plural ***hard times*** becomes the more common usage...

[image]

Broadly speaking the two usages are "equivalent", but at least *sometimes*, the plural version really does carry a more "literal" sense of ***many** times* and/or *over an **extended** period of time*.